# What database-as-a-service providers (ideally either Mongo or MySQL data sources) offer a REST API for retrieving data as JSON?

Tags: mysql, json, mongodb, cloud, mlab

We would like to hook up an iPhone app directly to a database in the cloud. From the iPhone app, we would like to use some REST API to retrieve data from the cloud database. We prefer using MySQL or Mongo as the data store.

We prefer not setting up our database system on AWS or another hosted provider. We would like a cloud service that offers the database layer out of the box.

What database-as-a-service companies support this, and what are the pros/cons of each?

Comment: Hey dude, check it out http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20782/mongodb-hosting-mongolab-vs-mongohq-vs-mongomachine

Comment: Thanks, @SushantGupta. Anything for MySQL?

Comment: Hey, do chk out Xeround and Microsoft SQL Azure http://readwrite.com/2011/01/12/7-cloud-based-database-service

Comment: Thanks, we're looking at Xeround, but it's not clear that we can access data via some REST API.

Comment: Are you wanting something that has a REST API without any additional wrapping necessary? (Don't you need authentication/etc/business logic?) MongoDB doesn't have a production ready REST API.

Comment: Thanks, @WiredPrairie. We will put the logic in the JavaScript. No authentication needed. There is no private or user-specific data stored -- only product data. Any suggestions?

Comment: Read-only? (I think MongoDB is typically more expensive to host than many other more traditional RDBMS systems if that matters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We looked around, and it seems like MongoLab is the only service offering a REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo is a great database for API interaction as the query language uses javascript expressions. Here are the open source API libraries that are implemented in Python

1. [Sleepy Mongoose](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2010/02/22/sleepy-mongoose-a-mongodb-rest-interface/)
2. [Eve](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve)

Primary advantage

- JavaScript can handle the querying part of data retrieval

Primary disadvantage

- The API libraries above have difficulty capturing complex queries